# How to add a blinking cursor in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

so I was trying to add blinking cursors for my text. I don't know why the cursor only appears at y=0, not at each text box. I was trynna add a cursor for each box when active and stop blitting when not active. I suspect it goes wrong because I got my declaration wrong or the blitting part. Can anyone point out where it goes wrong/ how to fix it? Thanks

```
import pygame
import datetime
import time

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.font.init()

# Note
finish = 0
leftover = 0

# Font
numb_font = pygame.font.Font(Arial, 14)
text_font = pygame.font.Font(Arial, 16)

color = (233, 248, 215)
active = False

# screen resolution
Width = 800
Height = 600
#bg = pygame.image.load('opennote.png')
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((Width, Height))

# Time
time_box = pygame.Rect(250, 63, 50, 30)
date_box = pygame.Rect(221, 27, 50, 30)
# boxes numb
leftover_box = pygame.Rect(265, 105, 30, 30)
finish_box = pygame.Rect(325, 105, 30, 30)


class InputBox:

    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, text=''):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, w, h)
        self.color = color
        self.text = text
        self.txt_surface = text_font.render(text, True, self.color)
        self.active = False
        self.score = 1
        # Cursor declare
        self.txt_rect = self.txt_surface.get_rect()
        self.cursor = pygame.Rect(self.txt_rect.topright, (3, self.txt_rect.height + 2))

    def handle_event(self, event):
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # If the user clicked on the input_box rect.
            if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                # Toggle the active variable.
                self.active = not self.active
            else:
                self.active = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if self.active:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    print(self.text)
                    global leftover
                    leftover += self.score
                    self.score = 0
                    self.text = ''
                    self.active = False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                    self.text = self.text[:-1]
                else:
                    self.text += event.unicode
                    # Cursor

                    self.txt_rect.size = self.txt_surface.get_size()
                    self.cursor.topleft = self.txt_rect.topright

                    # Limit characters           -20 for border width
                    if self.txt_surface.get_width() > self.rect.w - 15:
                        self.text = self.text[:-1]

    def draw(self, screen):
        # Blit the text.
        screen.blit(self.txt_surface, (self.rect.x + 5, self.rect.y + 10))
        # Blit the rect.
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, self.rect, 1)
        # Blit the  cursor
        if time.time() % 1 > 0.5:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, self.cursor)

    def update(self):
        # Re-render the text.
        self.txt_surface = text_font.render(self.text, True, self.color)


def main():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    input_box1 = InputBox(115, 170, 250, 36)
    input_box2 = InputBox(115, 224, 250, 36)
    input_box3 = InputBox(115, 278, 250, 36)
    input_box4 = InputBox(115, 333, 250, 36)
    input_box5 = InputBox(115, 386, 250, 36)
    input_box6 = InputBox(115, 440, 250, 36)
    input_box7 = InputBox(115, 494, 250, 36)
    input_box8 = InputBox(440, 170, 250, 36)
    input_box9 = InputBox(440, 224, 250, 36)
    input_box10 = InputBox(440, 278, 250, 36)
    input_box11 = InputBox(440, 333, 250, 36)
    input_box12 = InputBox(440, 386, 250, 36)
    input_box13 = InputBox(440, 440, 250, 36)
    input_box14 = InputBox(440, 494, 250, 36)
    input_box15 = InputBox(440, 115, 250, 36)
    input_box16 = InputBox(440, 61, 250, 36)
    input_boxes = [input_box1, input_box2, input_box3, input_box4, input_box5, input_box6, input_box7, input_box8,
                   input_box9, input_box10, input_box11, input_box12, input_box13, input_box14, input_box15, input_box16]
    done = False

    while not done:
        # Background
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        #screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        date_now = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
        time_now = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
            for box in input_boxes:
                box.handle_event(event)

        for box in input_boxes:
            box.update()

        for box in input_boxes:
            box.draw(screen)
            # Real Time
            # Date
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, 'white', date_box, -1)
        datebox_surface = numb_font.render(date_now, True, color)
        screen.blit(datebox_surface, (date_box.x + 5, date_box.y + 5))
        # Time
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, 'white', time_box, -1)
        timebox_surface = numb_font.render(time_now, True, color)
        screen.blit(timebox_surface, (time_box.x + 5, time_box.y + 5))

        # finish &Leftover
        # finish box
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, 'white', finish_box, -1)
        finishbox_surface = numb_font.render(str(finish), True, color)
        screen.blit(finishbox_surface, finish_box)
        # Leftover box
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, 'white', leftover_box, -1)
        leftover_box_surface = numb_font.render(str(leftover), True, color)
        screen.blit(leftover_box_surface, leftover_box)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(120)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to set the position of the cursor. Get the right center  position of the bounding rectangle of the text and set the left center position of the cursor:

```py
class InputBox:
    # [...]

    def draw(self, screen):
        # Blit the text.
        screen.blit(self.txt_surface, (self.rect.x + 5, self.rect.y + 10))
        # Blit the rect.
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, self.rect, 1)
        # Blit the  cursor
        if time.time() % 1 > 0.5:

            # bounding rectangle of the text
            text_rect = self.txt_surface.get_rect(topleft = (self.rect.x + 5, self.rect.y + 10))

            # set cursor position
            self.cursor.midleft = text_rect.midright

            pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, self.cursor)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is in the `__init__()` of your `InputBox` class.

```
class InputBox:

    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, text=''):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, w, h)
        self.color = color
        self.text = text
        self.txt_surface = text_font.render(text, True, self.color)
        self.active = False
        self.score = 1
        # Cursor declare
        self.txt_rect = self.txt_surface.get_rect()
        self.cursor = pygame.Rect(self.txt_rect.topright, (3, self.txt_rect.height + 2))
```

`self.text_surface` is the result of a call to the `.render` method of a `pygame.font.Font` object. This method-call returns a `pygame.Surface` object. The `Surface` object returned, however, doesn't have a position yet. Therefore, in the line where you have `self.txt_rect = self.txt_surface.get_rect()`, the `pygame.Rect` object that is returned has by default its topleft coordinate at (0, 0) (see [the documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect)).

This is easily fixed. You just need to replace `self.txt_rect = self.txt_surface.get_rect()` with `self.txt_rect = self.txt_surface.get_rect(topleft=(x, y))`.